# Como leer un xml de respuesta WS con php

Tags: php, xml

1. Hola, estoy recibiendo una respuesta de un web service en xml bajo un formato, pero, no logro recorrerlo, agradecería su gentil apoyo para esta pregunta en php7.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns2:invokeResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.ce.ebiz.com/"><return><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ebizResponse>
    <genericInvokeResponse>
        <commonResponse>
            <summaryResult/>
            <status>OK</status>
            <descriptionStatus>SUCCESFULL</descriptionStatus>
        </commonResponse>
        <xmlResult>
            <document>
                <typeDocument>03</typeDocument>
                <idDocument>B018-00001000</idDocument>
                <status>SIGNED</status>
                <statusDocument>EM_01</statusDocument>
                <statusSunat>PE_09</statusSunat>
                <declareTime>2021-06-20</declareTime>
                <signatureValue>OsKZ1abtMdghTP9ti0pdg+GC9gSWGC7XxdaBxMXI9D8AwjnN0fko8m3bsyggRTSx69k9MLQQJ+I6j4P/g25Eyoos/MuFg0yUt9kj7sacL7/JlfeIXmx0dhOao1ZQRZ96yNTEHabqNog9XDH0vWZk5dvreP2Ml5sFuNuaD60LU1Y=</signatureValue>
                <emisionTime>2021-06-20</emisionTime>
                <hashCode>OfDpJyUdUCEAA7AD4W4/DosB0t8=</hashCode>
                <pdfFileUrl>http://testing.bizlinks.com.pe/sfeperufiles/files/x%275A556573616D42526B647250546967416D5A4539687937547A5153414C686E31514F7072666F4B382F766466392B752F68723235356952582F6949474F475A6E%27</pdfFileUrl>
                <xmlFileSignUrl>http://testing.bizlinks.com.pe/sfeperufiles/files/x%274F7372717353565334492B48464A7463624546553738623677713470692B33314F764D63756377576A65737169334A3461547839335A756F4D447A4A2F555235%27</xmlFileSignUrl>
                <xmlFileSunatUrl>http://testing.bizlinks.com.pe/sfeperufiles/files/x%276B793753686B6F4B4E79376F6B714A4B4A43676C733651784B437548686B6F37567775516C71774238614A3779527076324B644453374A424849706453644B4D3757482F3450504443324D3D%27</xmlFileSunatUrl>
                <tipoDocumentoEmisor>6</tipoDocumentoEmisor>
                <numeroDocumentoEmisor>20531452055</numeroDocumentoEmisor>
                <tipoDocumentoAdquiriente>1</tipoDocumentoAdquiriente>
                <numeroDocumentoAdquiriente>71590424</numeroDocumentoAdquiriente>
                <adicionales xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            </document>
        </xmlResult>
    </genericInvokeResponse>
</ebizResponse>
</return></ns2:invokeResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
?>
```

Lo quiero es recorrer el xml, pero, no logro recorrer y conseguir el dato de: ebizresponse->genericInvokeResponse->commonResponse->status

```
<?php
# Util para debugging
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
var_dump($xml);
?>
```

Comment: El identificador de cierre de `heredoc` *"no debe estar sangrado"*. Además que no lo necesitas; puedes hacer simplemente `$respuesta = simplexml_load_string($response);`

Comment: reformule la pregunta estimado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que tienes un xml dentro de otro, prueba con:

```
$xmlSoap = simplexml_load_string($xml_str);
$xmlEbiz = simplexml_load_string( (string)$xmlSoap->children('soapenv',true)->Body
                                                  ->children('ns2',true)->invokeResponse
                                                  ->children('',true)->return
                                );
$status = $xmlEbiz->genericInvokeResponse->commonResponse->status;
echo $status;
```

Comment: eres un genio, me corrió perfectamente, muchas gracias estimado!!

Answer (score 1):

La funcion simplexml_load_string te devuelve un objeto y puedes recorrer el objeto como harias con cualquier otro de PHP, mira el siguient ejemplo.

```php
<?php

$xml_str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
       <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
       <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
       <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
       <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
       <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
       <YEAR>1985</YEAR> 
    </CD>
    <CD>
       <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
       <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
       <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
       <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
       <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
       <YEAR>1988</YEAR> 
    </CD>
    <CD>
       <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
       <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
       <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
       <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
       <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
       <YEAR>1982</YEAR> 
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
';

# Util para debugging
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_str);

foreach ($xml->CD as $item) {
    echo "Title: " . $item->TITLE . "<br />\r\n";
    echo "Artist: ". $item->ARTIST . "<br />\r\n";
}

/**** Imprimira

Title: Empire Burlesque
Artist: Bob Dylan
Title: Hide your heart
Artist: Bonnie Tyler
Title: Greatest Hits
Artist: Dolly Parton

****/

# Util para debugging
foreach( libxml_get_errors() as $error ) {
    print_r($error);
}

?>
```

En tu caso especifico, accede a la propiedad que corresponde del objeto

```php
<?php

$xml_str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ebizResponse>
  <genericInvokeResponse>
    <xmlResult>
      <document>
        <statusSunat>PE_09</statusSunat>
      </document>
    </xmlResult>
  </genericInvokeResponse>
</ebizResponse>
';


# Util para debugging
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_str);

# Accede a la propiedad del objeto
echo $xml->genericInvokeResponse->xmlResult->document->statusSunat;

# Imprime
# PE_09

foreach( libxml_get_errors() as $error ) {
    print_r($error);
}

?>
```

Segun tu mas reciente update no puedes acceder al objeto, porque la propiedad que busca no esta, al menos que hayas actualizado algo desde el 19, este es el response que se recibe de la solicitud enviada

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ebizResponse>
    <genericInvokeResponse>
        <commonResponse>
            <summaryResult>
                <total>1</total>
            </summaryResult>
            <status>OK</status>
            <descriptionStatus>SUCCESFULL</descriptionStatus>
        </commonResponse>
        <xmlResult>
            <document>
                <typeDocument>01</typeDocument>
                <idDocument>FBIZ-00000999</idDocument>
                <status>ERROR</status>
                <emisionTime>2021-06-19</emisionTime>
                <messages>
                    <codeStatus>400</codeStatus>
                    <descriptionStatus><![CDATA[Error al firmar]]></descriptionStatus>
                    <codeDetail>7074</codeDetail>
                    <descriptionDetail><![CDATA[El documento ya fue firmado]]></descriptionDetail>
                </messages>
                <tipoDocumentoEmisor>6</tipoDocumentoEmisor>
                <numeroDocumentoEmisor>20531452055</numeroDocumentoEmisor>
                <tipoDocumentoAdquiriente>6</tipoDocumentoAdquiriente>
                <numeroDocumentoAdquiriente>10715904247</numeroDocumentoAdquiriente>
                <adicionales xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            </document>
        </xmlResult>
    </genericInvokeResponse>
</ebizResponse>
```

No puedes acceder a: $xml->genericInvokeResponse->xmlResult->document->statusSunat; porque no existe.

Te recomendaria que remuevas ese codigo que incluye passwords y usuarios, solo el xml era necesario para hacer una prueba.

Comment: hola @augustoM, gracias por tu respuesta, lo intenté, pero, recibo una respuesta de error, mi código: `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
        $status_response = $xml->genericInvokeResponse->xmlResult->document->status;` y mi respuesta es: `Notice: Trying to get property 'document' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\grupoactiva.com.pe\controllers\c.facturation.php on line 529

Notice: Trying to get property 'status' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\grupoactiva.com.pe\controllers\c.facturation.php on line 529` mi línea 529 es $status_response

Comment: Entonces tienes un error en XML, revisa los errores de libxml_get_errors()

Comment: Pega el XML que estas recibiendo para revisarlo, no imagen ni pantallazo, codigo

Comment: Augusto, edite la pregunta original introduciendo el código de ejemplo que tengo para una cordial ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Fernando voy a actualizar la respuesta

Comment: Hola AugustoM me percato que la variable de respuesta tiene otro formato, actualice mi pregunta indicando la estructura que se recibe de la web service.